# Suspicious behavior between two MSE users

Tags: discussion, serial-voting, specific-user

In fact the purpose of this post is flagging one suspicious behavior between two MSE users.

But I'll start from something seemingly non related. In the question [Downvoting complete solution](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6302/downvoting-complete-solutions) there was a discussion of downvotes for the question and answers in the thread [Calculate the n-th term $1, -3, -7, \ldots$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208337/calculate-the-n-th-term-1-3-7-ldots).

I downvoted questioner (user [Ha Hi](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/39471/ha-hi)) because its question is extremely simple relative to his other questions. It is very suspicious to see a request for help in finding pattern in the sequence $1,-3,-7$ after asking help with the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\frac{a^{a^{x}}-{a^{x^{a}}}}{a^x-x^a}$

Also I downvoted answerer (user [Madrid Zhaku](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/34867/madrit-zhaku)) because he posted a [terrible answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/208341/19538). Moreover he posted [another terrible answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/205857/19538) to the similar question ([Find a formula for the real sequence $(a_n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205855/find-a-formula-for-the-real-sequence-a-n/205857#205857)) of the same questioner. I think this is a bad practice when one user provides complete and awful solutions to homework like questions.

Then I made a small investigation.

- 30 of 31 question of user Ha Hi where answered  by Madrit Zhaku and this answers were accepted. The only one not-answered question of Ha Hi is [Find the sum $\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 4}+\dots+\frac{1}{99\cdot 100}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194846/find-the-sum-frac12-cdot-3-frac13-cdot-4-dots-frac199-cdot-100) also contain answer of Madrit Zhaku.
- each answer of Madrit Zhaku on the questions of Ha Hi were posted on the average 5 minutes after Ha Hi asked the question. The best result of Madrit Zhaku is 2 minutes after question were posted (see thread [Find the sum $\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 4}+\dots+\frac{1}{99\cdot 100}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194846/find-the-sum-frac12-cdot-3-frac13-cdot-4-dots-frac199-cdot-100)). Also I recommend to take a look at the question [Prove the formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210369/prove-the-formula) where user [commenter](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/16627/commenter) asked Madrit Zhaku how he managed to write such a long answer in 3 minutes.
- answers of Madrit Zhaku to the question not asked by Ha Hi usually posted 2 hours later the question where asked.
- User Madrit Zhaku were registered 3 month ago, user Ha Hi were registered 37 days ago. Significant [increase of earning reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/34867/madrit-zhaku?tab=reputation) by Madrit Zhaku started September 8 i.e. 33 days ago

I think Ha Hi is a fake account for earning reputation by Madrit Zhaku.

Comment: I [learned](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3609/what-is-the-real-use-of-reputation/3610#comment13712_3610) that there is an automatic system to detect such things. It doesn't seem to be triggered yet...

Comment: Can someone explain why anyone would do this? The user would have to put pretty much effort for 10-15 credits, that can be used for... what?

Comment: @AD this increases USI

Comment: @Norbert Sure but only by little, and we don't talk about a university degree - so I cannot see the point of wasting the energy.

Comment: @hjg [see this](https://encyclopediadramatica.se/Unwarranted_Self-Importance)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Madrit Zhaku has apparently done this twice in the past, so he's been suspended for a year. In the future, please contact the moderators directly about such issues (for example via flagging).

Comment: I made this post to provide evidences

Comment: Moderator tools are more than capable of finding enough evidence. I'm not saying I don't appreciate you bringing this to our attention, but I think these sorts of things should be done privately in general.

Comment: How can I privately contact moderators?

Comment: Flagging is already enough in a situation like this.

Comment: @Norbert: all of the moderators' e-mail addresses are publicly available on this site. Click on our [name cards here](http://math.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: @WillieWong The only way I see to get the emails this way is if they have it on their homeage nd the homepage linked in the profile. I did not find your email adress.

Comment: @Michael: eh? Okay, that's bizarre. I clearly (perhaps falsely) remember there used to be a tick mark that gives permission to display my e-mail publicly. But I see that you are right, e-mails are not displayed to non-mod accounts! I've edited my profile to reflect this.

Comment: There used to also be an e-mail address on the bottom of the pages to which one can send e-mails and trust that they will eventually (a) be dealt with by SE employee if it is a technical issue and (b) be forwarded to the moderators. Now it seems that the e-mail address is replaced by a form. So that avenue is no longer available.

Comment: @WillieWong That form still sends a mail to the same address (which is team@stackexchange.com). And I don't think there was ever an option to display the mail address publicly, you have to write it manually in your "About" profile field.

Answer (score 19):

Perhaps it's worth mentioning here that it's okay to answer your own question **from a single account** (so that everyone knows what's going on).  From the FAQ:

> "It’s also OK to ask and answer your own question."

In fact, there's a specific button for it on the "Ask Question" page:

> [x] Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style

Comment: ...and earn the self-learner badge, maybe...